# Python script crashes (munmap_chunk invalid pointer)

Tags: python

I have a long running python script for a weather station. The script captures data from the weather sensors and uploads them to a mySql database as well as weather underground.

The issue I am having is that the script will run for multiple days and then crashes without a traceback. I have been troubleshooting this for weeks to no avail. I was initially running the script in IDLE. I have also ran it in the terminal. The latest update that I "think" is the real issue is that I ran the script in Visual Studio Code and when it crashed it posted: munmap_chunk() invalid pointer in the terminal.

My understanding is that munmap_chunk is a C issue so it is most likely being generated by a module that I import. I also understand that is is thrown when a pointer is passed to free() that hasn't been obtained through malloc().

With that said, I don't know how to narrow down where the issue is actually being generated from so I can potentially correct it.

Prior to seeing the munmap_chunk error I had thought maybe it was a memory leak somewhere. I manually called the garbage collector which in almost all cases you shouldn't do. That allowed for the script to run longer before the it finally crashed again.

The main thing I'm trying to determine is how to zero in on where the issue is coming from since the script just crashes and I don't get any traceback information or exception being thrown.

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
    
    from gpiozero import Button
    import time
    import math
    import Wind_Direction
    import statistics
    import Database
    import requests
    import sys
    import logging
    import board
    
    from adafruit_bme280 import basic as adafruit_bme280
   
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s **%(levelname)4s** - %(module)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', filename='/home/testa/testb/testc.txt', filemode = 'w', level=logging.DEBUG)
    
    logging.debug("The program has started")
    print ("\nWeather_Station_BYO: The program has started")
    
    i2c = board.I2C()   # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
    
    # ------- WU URL and credentials ---------
    
    WUurl = "https://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?"
    WUid = "TESTEST" # add your WS ID
    WUpwd = "TESTEST"  # add your password
    WUcreds = "ID=" + WUid + "&PASSWORD="+ WUpwd
    
    wind_count = 0          # Count how many half-rotations of the anemometer
    radius_in = 3.54        # Radius of your anemometer in inches (9 cm)
    wind_interval = 5       # How often (secs) to report speed
    interval = 300          # 5*60 seconds = 5 minutes = 300 seconds
    inches_in_mile = 63360
    SECS_IN_AN_HOUR = 3600
    ADJUSTMENT = 1.18       # Anemometer adjustment
    BUCKET_SIZE = 0.011     # Rain gauge tips once when (.2794 mm = .011 in) of rain falls
    rain_count = 0
    
    store_speeds = []
    store_directions = []
    
    def spin():
        
        """Counts the number of every half-rotation of the anenmometer and returns that count"""
        
        global wind_count
        
        wind_count = wind_count + 1 # Every half-rotation, add 1 to count
        
        # print("spin" + str(wind_count))
    
    def calculate_speed(time_sec):
        
        """Uses the number of half-rotations stored in the global variable wind_count and the time used to count the rotations and generates a final wind speed"""
        
        global wind_count
        
        circumference_in = (2 * math.pi) * radius_in
        
        rotations = wind_count / 2.0
    
        dist_in = (circumference_in * rotations) / inches_in_mile # Calculate distance travelled by a cup in inches
    
        mile_per_sec = dist_in / time_sec
        
        mph = mile_per_sec * SECS_IN_AN_HOUR
    
        final_speed = mph * ADJUSTMENT
    
        # print("final speed" + str(final_speed))
    
        return final_speed
    
    def bucket_tipped():
        
        """Counts the number of times the rain gauge bucket filled and tipped"""
        
        global rain_count
        
        rain_count = rain_count + 1
        
        # print(rain_count * BUCKET_SIZE)
    
    def reset_rainfall():
        
        """Resets the global rain_count variable set in the bucket_tipped function"""
        
        global rain_count
        
        rain_count = 0
    
    def reset_wind():
        
        """Resets the global wind_count variable set in the spin function"""
        
        global wind_count
        
        wind_count = 0
    
    def read_all():
        
        """Reads bme280 (temp, humididty, pressure) values converts them to proper units and calculates the dewpoint"""
    
        bme280 = adafruit_bme280.Adafruit_BME280_I2C(i2c)
    
        bme280.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25 # change this to match the location's pressure (hPa) at sea level
    
        humidity = bme280.humidity # % Relative humidity
    
        pressure = bme280.pressure * 100 / 3386  # Pascals converted to inHg
    
        ambient_temperature = bme280.temperature * 9/5 + 32  # Convert to fahrenheit rounded
    
        b = 17.62
        
        c = 243.12
        
        gamma = (b * bme280.temperature /(c + bme280.temperature)) + math.log(bme280.humidity / 100.0)
    
        dewpoint = (c * gamma) / (b - gamma)
         
        return humidity, pressure, ambient_temperature, dewpoint
    
    wind_speed_sensor = Button(5)
    
    wind_speed_sensor.when_pressed = spin  # Whenever the wind sensor magnet closes the reed switch then add 1 to the number of rotations
    
    # temp_probe = ds18b20_therm.DS18B20()
    
    rain_sensor = Button(6)
    
    rain_sensor.when_pressed = bucket_tipped
    
    db = Database.weather_database()
    
    i = 1
    while db.wxlogin() != True:
        time.sleep(30)
        i = i + 1
        if (i>5):
            logging.debug("Could not establish a connection to the mysql database and program will be terminated.")
            time.sleep(5)
            sys.exit("Could not establish connection") # Exit the script after i amount of connection attempts
    
    logging.debug("Initial connection to database was successful!")
    
    print("\nWeather_Station_BYO: Initial connection to database was successful!")
    
    # Loop to measure wind speed at 300-second intervals
    
    while True:
    
        try:
            start_time = time.time()
    
            while time.time() - start_time <= interval:
            
                # print("In loop 1")
                
                wind_start_time = time.time()
                
                reset_wind()
                
                while time.time() - wind_start_time <= wind_interval:
    
                    # print("In loop 2")
                    
                    store_directions.append(Wind_Direction.get_value(wind_interval)) # wind_interval is how long to take measuremennts for wind direction
                    
                final_speed = calculate_speed(wind_interval) # Add this speed to the list & wind_interval is how long to take measurements for wind speed
    
                store_speeds.append(final_speed)
    
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            
            logger.debug("Wind speed and direction obtained")
    
            # print("Out of both loops")
    
            # print("stored directions " + str(store_directions))
    
            # print("stored speeds " + str(store_speeds))
    
            wind_dir = Wind_Direction.get_average(store_directions)
            
            wind_gust = max(store_speeds)
            
            wind_speed = statistics.mean(store_speeds)
            
            rainfall = rain_count * BUCKET_SIZE
            
            reset_rainfall()
            
            store_speeds = []
            
            store_directions = []
        
            humidity, pressure, ambient_temp, dewpoint = read_all()
    
            logger.debug("Humidity, pressure, ambient_temp and dewpoint obtained")
            # print(wind_dir)
    
            if 348.75 <= wind_dir or wind_dir <= 11.25:
                wind_direction = 'N'
            elif 11.26 <= wind_dir <= 33.75:
                wind_direction = 'NNE'
            elif 33.76 <= wind_dir <= 56.25:
                wind_direction = 'NE'
            elif 56.26 <= wind_dir <= 78.75:
                wind_direction = 'ENE'
            elif 78.76 <= wind_dir <= 101.25:
                wind_direction = 'E'
            elif 101.25 <= wind_dir <= 123.75:
                wind_direction = 'ESE'
            elif 123.76 <= wind_dir <= 146.25:
                wind_direction = 'SE'
            elif 146.26 <= wind_dir <= 168.75:
                wind_direction = 'SSE'
            elif 168.76 <= wind_dir <= 191.25:
                wind_direction = 'S'
            elif 191.26 <= wind_dir <= 213.75:
                wind_direction = 'SSW'
            elif 213.76 <= wind_dir <= 236.25:
                wind_direction = 'SW'
            elif 226.26 <= wind_dir <= 258.75:
                wind_direction = 'WSW'
            elif 258.76 <= wind_dir <= 281.25:
                wind_direction = 'W'
            elif 281.26 <= wind_dir <= 303.75:
                wind_direction = 'WNW'
            elif 303.76 <= wind_dir <= 326.25:
                wind_direction = 'NW'
            elif 326.25 <= wind_dir <= 348.75:
                wind_direction = 'NNW'
            else: wind_direction = ''
        
            #print('',wind_direction, 'Wind Direction \n',round(wind_speed,1), 'Wind Speed (mph) \n', round(wind_gust,1),'Wind Gust (mph) \n', round(rainfall,1), 'Rainfall (in) \n',
               #   round(humidity,1), '% Relative Humidity \n', round(dewpoint,1), 'Dew Point F \n', round(pressure,2), 'Barometric Pressure (inHg) \n', round(ambient_temp,1), 'Temperature F \n')
            
            i = 1
            while db.check_connection() != True:
                time.sleep(30)
                i = i + 1
                if (i>5):
                    logger.debug("Connection to the mysql database was disconnected and connection could not be restablished. Program will be terminated.")
                    time.sleep(5)
                    sys.exit("Could not re-establish connection") # Exit the script after i amount of connection attempts
                db.wxlogin()
                
            db.insert(1,round(ambient_temp,1), 0, 0, round(pressure,2), round(humidity,1), round(dewpoint,1), wind_direction, round(wind_speed,1), round(wind_gust,1), round(rainfall,1)) # 10 items
    
            # Weatherunderground
            # print("Uploading to Weather Underground")
    
            f_date = "&dateutc=now"
            f_humid = "&humidity=" + str(humidity)              # % Relative humidity
            f_wspeed = "&windspeedmph=" + str(wind_speed)       # mph
            f_gust = "&windgustmph=" + str(wind_gust)           # mph
            f_airtemp = "&tempf=" +  str(ambient_temp)          # degrees F
            f_rain = "&rainin=" + str(rainfall)                 # inches
            f_press = "&baromin=" + str(pressure)               # inches
            # f_groundtemp = "&soiltempf=" + str(ground_temp_f) # degrees F
            f_winddir = "&winddir=" + str(wind_dir)             # degrees
            f_action = "&action=updateraw"
    
            try:
    
                r = requests.get(WUurl+WUcreds+f_date+f_humid+f_wspeed+f_winddir+f_gust+f_airtemp+f_rain+f_press+f_action, timeout = 30)
    
  
    
                print("\nReceived " + str(r.status_code) + " " + str(r.text) + " from WU")
    
            except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    
                logger.debug("HTTP Error - Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to the internet. Technical details given below.\n")
    
                logger.debug(str(e))
                
                print("\nHTTP Error - Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to internet. Technical details given below.\n")
    
                print(str(e))
                
                continue
    
            except requests.Timeout as e:
    
                logger.debug("HTTP Error - Timeout Error")
    
                logger.debug(str(e))
    
                print("\nHTTP Error - Timeout Error")
    
                print(str(e))
       
                continue
    
            except requests.RequestException as e:
    
                logger.debug("HTTP Error - General Error")
    
                logger.debug(str(e))
    
                print("\nHTTP Error - General Error")
    
                print(str(e))
        
                continue
    
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                
                print("\nSomeone closed the program")
    
            if (str(r.status_code) != '200'):
                logger.debug("Upload to Weather Underground was not sucessful. HTTP Response Code: " + str(r.status_code) + " " + str(r.text))
    
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("Unhandled exception in the script!", exc_info = True)
```

Traceback from faulthandler in VSCode:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Thread 0xb0fa5440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 539 in held
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 1054 in __call__

Thread 0xb27ff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 543 in held
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 1054 in __call__

Thread 0xb31ff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 246 in _on_run
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb3bff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 200 in _on_run
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb45ff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_timeout.py", line 43 in _on_run
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb4fff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 219 in _read_line
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 237 in _on_run
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb599b440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 179 in get
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 382 in _on_run
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0xb6f34b40 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/spi_devices.py", line 85 in _words_to_int
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/spi_devices.py", line 220 in _read
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/spi_devices.py", line 157 in value
  File "/home/pi/Liberty Ridge WX Reduced/Wind_Direction.py", line 97 in get_value
  File "/home/pi/Liberty Ridge WX Reduced/Liberty_Ridge_WX.py", line 199 in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96 in _run_module_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263 in run_path
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 285 in run_file
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 444 in main
  File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45 in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193 in _run_module_as_main
```

Traceback from faulthandler in terminal:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Thread 0xb44ff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 539 in held
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb4eff440 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 539 in held
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0xb6f53b40 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/spi_devices.py", line 85 in _words_to_int
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/spi_devices.py", line 220 in _read
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/spi_devices.py", line 157 in value
  File "/home/pi/Liberty Ridge WX Reduced/Wind_Direction.py", line 97 in get_value
  File "/home/pi/Liberty Ridge WX Reduced/Liberty_Ridge_WX.py", line 189 in <module>
Aborted
```

Comment: Enable the Python faulthandler to possibly get a better traceback when your program crashes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html

Comment: Secondly - set up e. g. a systemd service to manage the process and restart it in the case it crashes. (Of course fixing the root cause is a good idea too.)

Comment: I will run it with the faulthandler enabled. It will run for a few days before it crashes so it will take some time before I see if it will give a better traceback. If that fails I will end up having to use a systemd service or supervisor to force a restart if it crashes. I have been avoiding that since I would prefer to figure out what is actually causing the crash.

Comment: By the way... `board` and `adafruit_bme280` seem like CircuitPython things... What are you running this on?

Comment: It is running on a raspberry pi.

Comment: The script finally crashed with the munmap_chunk() error. A traceback was returned due to using faulthandler. With the information that was returned I'm not real sure where to go from here. I added the traceback to the original post for reference.

Comment: Well, for one you seem to be running the code under the VSCode debugger. Can you try running it without it, just straight from the command line?

Comment: I am running it from the terminal now. It will take a few days for it to crash again. I'll post an update with what is returned.

Comment: It crashed earlier this morning but I wasn't able to post the traceback until now. Any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running very similar code on my Raspberry Pi weather station, and also get the munmap_chunk() error after a couple of days, running either from a command line or from Thonny.

Like you, I get no information, apart from the munmap_chunk() line. That makes me think the error is not in Python, as that would surely provide trace information. So, maybe it's from the libraries Python uses, or from the part of the operating system that does memory management.

Here's what I believe to be the source code for where the error happens, and the comments are interesting...

```
static void
munmap_chunk (mchunkptr p)
{
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T size = chunksize (p);

  assert (chunk_is_mmapped (p));

  /* Do nothing if the chunk is a faked mmapped chunk in the dumped
     main arena.  We never free this memory.  */
  if (DUMPED_MAIN_ARENA_CHUNK (p))
    return;

  uintptr_t block = (uintptr_t) p - prev_size (p);
  size_t total_size = prev_size (p) + size;
  /* Unfortunately we have to do the compilers job by hand here.  Normally
     we would test BLOCK and TOTAL-SIZE separately for compliance with the
     page size.  But gcc does not recognize the optimization possibility
     (in the moment at least) so we combine the two values into one before
     the bit test.  */
  if (__builtin_expect (((block | total_size) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) != 0, 0))
    malloc_printerr ("munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer");

  atomic_decrement (&mp_.n_mmaps);
  atomic_add (&mp_.mmapped_mem, -total_size);

  /* If munmap failed the process virtual memory address space is in a
     bad shape.  Just leave the block hanging around, the process will
     terminate shortly anyway since not much can be done.  */
  __munmap ((char *) block, total_size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided a better thing to do was restart the program once a day, but I didn't want to use crontab, rc.local or similar. There's actually a way for a Python program to restart itself! I found it here https://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/03/23/restarting-a-python-script-within-itself/

Here's my test program...

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python3
import sys
import os
import time
import datetime as dt

began = dt.datetime.now()
print("Began at  ", str(began))
ending = began + dt.timedelta(minutes = 2)
print("Ending at ", str(ending))

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    present = dt.datetime.now()    
    print("     It's ", str(present))
    
    if present > ending:
        print("Time's up!")
        os.execv(sys.executable, ['python3'] + sys.argv)
        quit()
```

I think amending your weather station code to restart itself daily, before the munmap_chunk() error happens is likely to be easier than finding out why it happens.

**Update:**
That's what I did, adding this code before the main loop...

```
ending = dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(hours = 24)
```

...and this at the end of the main loop

```
present = dt.datetime.now()
if present > ending:
    print("Time for my 24 hour restart!")
    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python3'] + sys.argv)
    quit()
```

The program restarts every day (approximately), and has so far run for five days without the **munmap_chunk()** error.

[image: Restart log file]